# How do I clear "Variable ... used before being initialized" error when the variable is first used in its own initialization?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scope, variable-assignment

**Background:** I am using Core Data to handle persistent storage for my app's user settings. One of my settings is a `Color` value that I am translating into RGB values stored as properties of an object of type `InitialsImageColor` which is managed by Core Data. The `Color` is selected using a `ColorPicker` in a `Form` view.

**Problem:** I have a variable `imageColor` that I am initializing in a view's `init()` declaration. The compiler throws an error saying "Variable 'self.imageColor' used before being initialized" ***5 times***. Here is the relevant code portion with comments for clarity:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    // Access the managed object context for saving changes to Core Data
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    // Load stored InitialsImageColor objects from Core Data
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var colorSetting: FetchedResults<InitialsImageColor>
    
    // A Color variable for the ColorPicker View to bind to
    @State private var imageColor: Color

    // A String variable for the Form View's .searchable modifier to bind to
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    
    // A Bool variable to change to make the .sheet containing SettingsView to disappear
    @Binding var showSettings: Bool
    
    // An initializer to set the starting value for the ColorPicker View to use
    init() {
        imageColor = Color(                        // This line throws error
            red: colorSetting.first?.r ?? 255.0,   // This line throws error
            green: colorSetting.first?.g ?? 255.0, // This line throws error
            blue: colorSetting.first?.b ?? 255.0,  // This line throws error
            opacity: colorSetting.first?.a ?? 1.0  // This line throws error
        )
    }
```

1. How is this even possible? The first use of the variable is in the initializer itself. This error shouldn't happen.
2. What do I do to fix it?

Originally, I tried to initialize `imageColor` in its declaration, but of course that didn't work, because it uses another variable to come up with its value and the scope is outside the `body` of the view. I placed it in the `init()` declaration to solve that problem, and then this happened.

Comment: Why not have a computed property on InitialsImageColor that return a Color representation of the values?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can I do that? In my core data model I am not given `Color` as an option when choosing an attribute type for my entity, or I would have done that instead of breaking it into component `Double`s.

Comment: No I said a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/properties#Computed-Properties) that you could add in a extension to your entity class.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ah. You left out the part about an extension in your original comment. It hadn't occurred to me that I could extend a managed class, much less to extend it with an attribute of a type not allowed by the data model. I tried it, and it indeed simplified my code. I was able to use that property whenever I needed to use the stored color information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your code here. First, `imageColor` has a a `@State` property wrapper, which means you actually want to initialise it like so:

```swift
_imageColor = State(initialValue: Color(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1)
```

You could just as easily write this at the declaration, though:

```
// A Color variable for the ColorPicker View to bind to
@State private var imageColor = Color(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1)
```

Because the second problem is that you are expecting the fetch request to have happened during init. That isn't the case. You can and should expect SwiftUI views to be initialised and destroyed many times, outwith your control. With that philosophy in mind, you can see that it doesn't make sense to have executed the fetch request on initialisation. It will be executed when the `body` of the view is evaluated.

A better solution may be to have the color defined as a custom binding, rather than a separate state variable, which you can then pass to the other view:

```
private var imageColor: Binding<Color> {
    Binding<Color>(
        get: { 
            Color(                        
                red: colorSetting.first?.r ?? 255.0, 
                green: colorSetting.first?.g ?? 255.0,
                blue: colorSetting.first?.b ?? 255.0, 
                opacity: colorSetting.first?.a ?? 1.0 
            )
        },
        set: {
            // Write back to your data object
        }
    )
}
```

(I left your 255 values in here as I just copied from the question)

Comment: Thanks for that @jrturton. I actually found a workaround, as shown in my own answer, that was similar to your bit about `Color(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1)`. I didn't know about the state variable declaration syntax you displayed in the first part of your answer, nor did I know about custom bindings. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: I tried your custom binding solution, and I rather preferred it over what I was doing before. So answer accepted! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. After doing some thinking, realized I didn't actually need `imageColor` to be initially tied to my persistent data object (I had been thinking using a paradigm associated with older attempts that involved `UserDefaults`). So I initialized it in its declaration thus:

`@State private var imageColor: Color = .white`

Then I merely updated the value in the initializer (without changing my code at all **[but see edit]**).

That produced a similar error, however. It now told me that a different variable, `@Binding var showSettings: Bool` was doing the same thing: "Variable 'self.showSettings' used before being initialized". I found a workaround for that too. Rather than using that to dismiss the .sheet, I simply declared an environment variable using the dismiss keyframe thus:

`@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss`

Then I called it with my `Done` button, rather than setting `showSettings = false`.

**EDIT:** After building and opening the view, I got this warning: "Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time." And it behaved just the way the warning indicated. So I removed the initializer and placed its code in a `.onAppear` modifier for the `Form` view (and I changed the nil coalescing to a force-unwrap, since I used an `if` block to evaluate `!colorSetting.isEmpty` before running the property-setting code).